# Header not showing up?

Tags: html, css, header

So I am pretty much mind boggled on why my header isn't showing up. I've tried about everything. I messed up on it a bit when typing it out, but it still should've shown up itself.

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="header">
<div id="logo">
<img src="../Images/logo.png">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color:#2A2B2D;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.header {
    background-color:#2C2E31
    border-bottom:#000000 2px solid;
    top repeat-x;
    height:182px;
}
```

Comment: What is `top repeat-x;`?

Comment: What's this line `top repeat-x;` supposed to do?

Comment: top repeat-x; for  background-color:#2C2E31 i guess

Comment: I thought it was suppose to expand it horizontally forever?

Comment: It repeats the background image (if you use it right) but you aren't using a background image...

Comment: What did you expect to see? The HTML has no content, and the style sheet is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jYbfc/

you should use

```
 width:100%;
```

if you want the width to be the same size as the page. also you forgot a ";" after your background-color.

```
body {
    background:#2A2B2D;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.header {
    background:#2C2E31;
    border-bottom:#000000 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height:182px;
}
```

Comment: oops haha, I forgot to update it, so it didn't have a link yet.

Answer (score -1):

u had a type error

[This is your mistake](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/EEfhV/)

```
   body {
        background-color:#2A2B2D;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .header {
        background-color:#2C2E31; <<< u missed  ;
        border-bottom:#000000 2px solid;
        height:182px;
    }
```

[See after correct it](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/EEfhV/1/)

Comment: `background-color` cannot have those properties - it must be `background`